# Estou aprendendo sobre a biblioteca TKinter, mas meu código ta dando esse erro"'type' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x

```
def bt_click(botao):
    print(botao["text"])

janela = Tk()

bt1 = Button(janela, width=20, text= "botão 1")
bt1["command"]= partial(bt_click, bt1)
bt1.place(x=100, y=100)

bt2 = Button(janela, width=20, text="botão 2")
bt2["command"] = partial[bt_click, bt2]
bt2.place(x=200, y=200)

janela.geometry("300x300+200+200")
janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: Estão faltando os "import" no seu código. Seria interessante editar sua resposta e acrescentar a mensagem de erro completa.

Comment: Onde você está definindo `partial`. Seria uma função? Complemente com o [código mínimo para reprodução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

O erro me parece estar nesta linha:

```
bt2["command"] = partial[bt_click, bt2]
```

Você está usando como se fosse um dicionário (de duas chaves?), enquanto que na primeira ocasião, você chamou como uma função. Mude para

```
bt2["command"] = partial(bt_click, bt2)
```